# What is the difference between the ARM, Thumb and Thumb 2 instruction encodings?

Tags: arm, thumb

I am a bit confused about instruction sets. There are Thumb, ARM and Thumb 2. From what I have read Thumb instructions are all 16-bit but inside the **ARMv7M user manual** (page vi) there are Thumb 16-bit and Thumb 32-bit instructions mentioned.

Now I have to overcome this confusion. It is said that Thumb 2 supports 16-bit and 32-bit instructions. So is ARMv7M in fact supporting Thumb 2 instructions and not just Thumb?

One more thing. Can I say that Thumb (32-bit) is the same as ARM instructions which are allso 32-bit?

Comment: *Can I say that Thumb (32-bit) is the same as ARM instructions which are also 32-bit?* The answer to that is no.  Thumb2 is a mix of 32/16bits with different encodings than straight ARM 32bit.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Oh, ARM and their silly naming...

It's a common misconception, but officially there's no such thing as a "Thumb-2 instruction set".

Ignoring ARMv8 (where everything is renamed and AArch64 complicates things), from ARMv4T to ARMv7-A there are two **instruction sets**: ARM and Thumb. They are both "32-bit" in the sense that they operate on up-to-32-bit-wide data in 32-bit-wide registers with 32-bit addresses. In fact, where they overlap they represent the exact same instructions - it is only the instruction **encoding** which differs, and the CPU effectively just has two different decode front-ends to its pipeline which it can switch between. For clarity, I shall now deliberately avoid the terms "32-bit" and "16-bit"...

ARM instructions have fixed-width 4-byte encodings which require 4-byte alignment. Thumb instructions have variable-length (2 or 4-byte, now known as "narrow" and "wide") encodings requiring 2-byte alignment - most instructions have 2-byte encodings, but `bl` and `blx` have always had 4-byte encodings<sup>*</sup>. The really confusing bit came in ARMv6T2, which introduced "Thumb-2 Technology". Thumb-2 encompassed not just adding a load more instructions to Thumb (mostly with 4-byte encodings) to bring it almost to parity with ARM, but also extending the execution state to allow for conditional execution of most Thumb instructions, and finally introducing a whole new assembly syntax (UAL, "Unified Assembly Language") which replaced the previous separate ARM and Thumb syntaxes and allowed writing code once and assembling it to either instruction set without modification.

The Cortex-M architectures only implement the Thumb instruction set - ARMv7-M (Cortex-M3/M4/M7) supports most of "Thumb-2 Technology", including conditional execution and encodings for VFP instructions, whereas ARMv6-M (Cortex-M0/M0+) only uses Thumb-2 in the form of a handful of 4-byte system instructions.

Thus, the new 4-byte encodings (and those added later in ARMv7 revisions) are still **Thumb instructions** - the "Thumb-2" aspect of them is that they *can have* 4-byte encodings, and that they can (mostly) be conditionally executed via `it` (and, I suppose, that their menmonics are only defined in UAL).

<sub>* Before ARMv6T2, it was actually a complicated implementation detail as to whether `bl` (or `blx`) was executed as a 4-byte instruction or as a pair of 2-byte instructions. The architectural definition was the latter, but since they could only ever be executed as a pair in sequence there was little to lose (other than the ability to take an interrupt halfway through) by fusing them into a single instruction for performance reasons. ARMv6T2 just redefined things in terms of the fused single-instruction execution</sub>

Comment: As well, within *Thumb2*, there are op-codes that have been added over time.  So not all *Thumb2* is the same.  From the main CPU perspective, there is no mode known as *Thumb2* (I think that is what you mean by 'official'?); certainly ARM holding seems to have an idea of *Thumb2* as being mixed 16/32 bit encodings, but other than that it is nebulous.

Comment: Thank you! This sorts things out for me. Anyway I went to an Embedded World fair held in Nürnberg two days ago and it was awesome. I got so much info on ARM. Amazing event!

Comment: So does parameter `-mthumb-interwork` actually alows combining of (a) Thumb16 with Thumb32 or (b) Thumb16&32 with ARM? Curently I am assembling using `-mthumb` parameter and in source file I am using `.syntax unified` in order for assembler to alow usage of Thumb16 and Thumb32 encodings. But could I remove `.syntax unified` from my source file and use `-mthumb-interwork` parameter at assemble time instead? Documentation is not perfectly clear about that...

Comment: Cortex M4 is `armv7e-m`

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I disagree with the statement "there's no such thing as a Thumb-2 instruction set", because ARM's official website has a page titled ["The Thumb-2 instruction set"](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0338/g/introduction/arm1156t2-s-architecture-with-thumb-2-core-technology/the-thumb-2-instruction-set)

Comment: @GandhiGandhi At the time of the writing, there was none.  Also, the page you link is general information.  Specific CPUs add different opcodes, so the web page by itself doesn't define **Thumb2** in a strict sense.  It does contain the ideas behind it.  Critically as pointed out, there is no 'Thumb2' CPU mode; so this definition of Thumb2 is an evolution of the Thumb mode.  This matters to system programmers trying to get to 'Thumb2' mode.

Comment: So confusing, so I chose RISC-V

Answer (score 27):

In addition to [Notlikethat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28670713/563188), and as it hints at, ARMv8 introduces some new terminology to try to reduce the confusion (of course adding even more new terminology):

There is a 32-bit execution state (AArch32) and a 64-bit execution state (AArch64).

The 32-bit execution state supports two different instruction sets: T32 ("Thumb") and A32 ("ARM"). The 64-bit execution state supports only one instruction set - A64.

All A64, like all A32, instructions are 32-bit (4 byte) in size, requiring 4-byte alignment.

Many/most A64 instructions can operate on both 32-bit and 64-bit registers (or arguably 32-bit or 64-bit views of the same underlying 64-bit register).

All ARMv8 processors (like all ARMv7 processors) that implement AArch32 support Thumb-2 instructions in the T32 instruction set.

Not all ARMv8-A processors implement AAarch32, and some don't implement AArch64. Some Processors support both, but only support AArch32 at lower exception levels.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on unixsmurf's answer directly but it needs a tweak. An ARMv8A processor core has the choice to not implement aarch32 state at all. Such a core would not support T32 nor A32 instructions. If a given processor core _does_ implement the aarch32 state (like ARM ltds' cortex-A53,A57, and A72) then it also supports Thumb-2 mode in that state.

Comment: @wmills: you just have commented on it directly :) You could add your own clarification as an answer.

Comment: @wmills Indeed, since this answer was written, [some of them don't support AArch64 either](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a32-processor.php) ;)

Answer (score 12):

**Thumb**: 16 bit instruction set

**ARM**: 32 bit wide instruction set hence more flexible instructions and less code density

**Thumb2 (mixed 16/32 bit)**: somehow a compromise between *ARM* and *thumb(16)* (mixing them), to get both performance/flexibility of ARM and instruction density of Thumb. so a Thumb2 instruction can be either an ARM (only a subset of) with 32 bit wide instruction or a Thumb instruction with 16 bit wide.

Comment: Actually, this is a good simple answer, for generic understanding as the details are gory.  Thumb1 limited registers and this had an impact on performance.  With thumb2, you have almost all the functionality of ARM32 with a compressed instruction stream.  The result in that Thumb2 is more performant (less instruction fetching) and has smaller code size for almost all cases.

Comment: Thumb2 32-bit instructions have a different encoding than their ARM mode equivalent. Thinking of Thumb2 as including actual ARM instructions might be a useful simplification, but if you look at the details, there's a difference.  ARM modes uses 4 bits in every instruction for predication. Thumb2 mode uses a bit to signal whether an instruction is 1 or 2 chunks of 16-bit, and still needs an `it` instruction to predicate later instructions.

Answer (score 6):

It was confusing for me the Cortex M3 having 4-byte instructions, yet not executing the ARM instructions. Or CPUs capable to have 2-byte and 4-byte opcodes, but capable to execute the ARM instructions too. So I read a book about Arm and now I understand it slightly better. Still, the naming and the overlap are still confusing to me. I was thinking it would be interesting to compare a few CPUs first and then talk about the ISAs.

To compare a few CPUs and what they can do and how they overlap:

- Cortex **M0/M0+/M1/M23** are considered **Thumb** (Thumb-1) and can execute the **2-byte** opcodes which are limited compared to others. However, some instructions such as `mrs`, `msr`, `bl`, `dmb`, `dsb`, `isb` are from Thumb-2 and are **4-byte**. The Cortex M0/M0+/M1 are ARMv6, while Cortex M23 is ARMv8. The Thumb-1 instruction was extended in the ARMv7, so it can be said that ARMv8 Cortext M23 supports fuller Thumb-1 (except `it` instruction) while ARMv6 Cortex M0/M0+ only a subset of the ISA (they are missing specifically `it`, `cbz` and `cbnz` instructions). I might be wrong (please correct me if this is not right), but noticed something funny, that only CPUs I see which support Thumb-1 fully are CPUs that already support Thumb-2 as well, I do not know Thumb-1 only CPU which supports 100% of Thumb-1. I think it's because of the `it` which could be seen as Thumb-2 opcode which is 2-byte and was in essence added to Thumb-1. On the Thumb-1 CPUs the 4-byte opcodes could be seen as two 2-bytes to represent the 4-byte opcode instead.
- Cortex **M3/M4/M7/M33/M35P/M55** can execute **2-byte and 4-byte** opcodes, both are **Thumb-1 and Thumb-2** and support a full set of the ISAs. The 2-byte and 4-byte opcodes are mixed more evenly, while the Cortex M0/M0+/M1/M23 above are biased to use 2-byte opcodes most of the time. Cortex M3/M4/M7 are ARMv7, while Cortex M33/M35P/M55 are ARMv8.
- Cortex **A/R** can accept both **ARM and Thumb** opcodes and therefore have **2-byte and 4-byte**. To switch between the modes the PC needs to be offset by one byte (forcefully unaligned), this can be done for example with branch instruction `bx` which sets the `T` bit of the `CPSR` and switches the mode depending on the lowest bit of address. This works well, for example when calling subroutine the PC (and its mode) get saved, then inside the subroutine it could be switched to Thumb mode, yet when returning from Thumb mode it will restore the PC (and its T-bit) and switches back to whatever the caller was (ARM or Thumb mode) without any issue.
- **ARM7** only supports **ARMv3 4-byte** ISA
- **ARM7T** supports both **Thumb-1 and ARM** ISAs (2-byte and 4-byte)
- **ARM11** (ARMv6, ARMv6T2, ARMv6Z, ARMv6K) supports **Thumb-1, Thumb-2 and ARM** ISAs

The book I referenced stated that in the ARMv7 **and newer** the architecture switched from Von Neumann (data and instructions sharing a bus) to Harvard (dedicated busses) to get better performance. However the absolute term "and newer" is not true, because ARMv8 is newer, yet the ARMv8 Cortex M23 is Von Neumann.

The ISAs are:

- **ARM** has 16 registers (R0-R12, SP, LR, PC), only 4-byte opcodes, there are revisions to the ISA, but they are only 4-byte opcodes.
- **Thumb** (aka Thumb-1) split the 16 registers to lower (R0-R7) and higher (R8-R12, SP, LR, PC), most instructions can access the lower set only, while only some can access the higher set. Only 2-byte opcodes. On low-end devices which have a 16-bit bus (and have to do 32-bit word access in two steps) perform better when they they execute 2-byte opcodes as it's matching their bus. The naming is confusing me the Thumb could be used as the family term for both Thumb-1 together with Thumb-2, or sometimes Thumb can be used for Thumb-1 only. I think the Thumb-1 is not an official Arm term, just something I have seen used by people to make the distinguishment between the Thumb family of both ISAs and the first Thumb ISA clearer. Instructions in ARM can have the optional `s` suffix to update the `CPSR` register (for example `ands`, `orrs`, `movs`, `adds`, `subs` instruction), while in the Thumb-1 the `s` is always on and it saves the `CPSR` register all the time. In some older toolchains the implicit `s` is not needed, however in the efforts of Unified Assembly Language (UAL) now it's a requirement to explicitly specify the `s` even when there is no option to not use the `s`.
- **Thumb-2** is an extension to Thumb and can access all registers like ARM does, has 4-byte opcodes with some differences compared to ARM. In the assembly, the Thumb-1 2-byte narrow opcode and Thumb-2 4-byte wide opcode can be forced with `.n` and `.w` postfix (example `orr.w`). The ARM and Thumb-2 opcode formats/encodings are different and their capabilities differ too. The conditional execution of instructions can be used, but only when `it` (if-then) instruction/block is prepended. This can be done explicitly or implied (and done by the toolchain behind the user's back). And the confusion might be actually good as Arm (the company) wanted them to be similar, a lot of effort went to Unified Assembly Language (UAL) so assembly files made for ARM could be compiled on Thumb-2 without change. If I understand this correctly, that can't be 100% guaranteed and some edge cases could probably be made where the ARM assembly can't compile as Thumb-2 and this is another absolute statement that is not fully true. For example the ARM7 `bl` instruction can address +-32MB while on Cortex M3 it can only +-16MB. The situation such be much better compared to Thumb-1 where the ARM assembly has to be more likely rewritten to target Thumb-1, while ARM to Thumb-2 rewrite is less likely to happen. Another difference are the data processing instructions. Both ARM and Thumb-2 support 8-bit immediates while ARM can rotate bits only to the right and only by even bits, while Thumb can do rotations to left and by even/odd amount of bits and on top of that allows repetitive byte patterns such as `0xXYXYXYXY`, `0x00XY00XY` or `0xXY00XY00`. Because the shifts are rotating, the left and right shifts can be achieved by 'overflowing', shifting so much to one direction that it's effectively a shift to the opposite direction `1 << (32 - n) == 1 >> n`

So in conclusion some Arm CPUs can do:

- only 4-byte opcode instructions which are pure ARM ISA
- 2-byte/4-byte Thumb-1/Thumb-2 ISAs with a focus to use the 2-byte most of the time with only a few 4-byte opcodes, these often are labeled as Thumb (Thumb-1) 2-byte opcode CPUs (and the few 4-byte opcodes are sometimes not mentioned)
- 2-byte/4-byte Thumb-1/Thumb-2 ISAs and are more evenly mixed between 2-byte and 4-byte opcodes, often labeled as Thumb-2
- 2-byte/4-byte opcodes by switching between ARM/Thumb modes

Reference for this information: ARM Assembly Language Programming & Architecture Muhammad Ali Mazidi et al 2016. The book was written before the company name change from ARM to Arm, so sometimes it was confusing when it was referencing the company Arm and when the ARM ISA.

Comment: I wanted to know if M4 processors could execute ARM as well as Thumb2. Yours is the only answer that solved my question. Thank you.

Comment: Really, what is the answer?  Thumb-1 is not on any Cortex-M CPU.  Thumb-1 is a completely different beast than what is on Cortex-M0.  16/32 bit encodings are not the only relevant portion to this question.  The M4 only supports Thumb(2) mode, even though the instructions are 16/32bit mix.

Comment: @artlessnoise From the Arm's document https://developer.arm.com/Processors/Cortex-M4 "ISA Support: Thumb or Thumb-2, featuring Hardware Divide (2-12 Cycles), Single-Cycle Multiply, bit field processing, Saturated Adjustment Support, DSP extension" So you saying Arm got their documentation wrong and only supports Thumb-2?

Comment: @artlessnoise Completely different beast? You mean M0 supports lacks that 'beast'? Something like Thumb1-withoutBeast mode? Arm's document: https://developer.arm.com/Processors/Cortex-M0 is saying: "Thumb or Thumb-2 subset". And I listed specific nuances about the instructions and their differences in M0, so people have more context what Thumb-1 and Thumb-2 support means practically. What is your abstract "different beast" mean? List all the instructions and their nuances when my list feels not relevant and wrong to you. M0 is very limited to others, but "different beast" has 0 information

Comment: Yes, ARM is redefining the concept. You can see notlikethat answer.  There are other entities like GCC, Clang, Apple, Samsung, Broadcom, etc. that will use these terms.  The Cortex-M0 can handle exception in Thumb mode.  The original 'Thumb-1' architecture required that you take exceptions in ARM32 mode.  There are other nuances as I tried to detail in my answer.  As you can see from [this post by UnixSmurf](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344456/could-some-of-the-arm-tags-be-merged), an ARM employee, they point out some redundancies in ARM naming.   It is a similar thing with thumb.

Answer (score 2):

> One more thing. Can I say that Thumb (32-bit) is the same as ARM instructions which are also 32-bit?

No. (my comment answered this)

> It is said that Thumb 2 supports 16-bit and 32-bit instructions. So is ARMv7M in fact supporting Thumb 2 instructions and not just Thumb?

This is correct in that ARMv7M support instructions beyond the initial ARM thumb.  It is often called Thumb-2, but that itself is nebulous.

---

There seems to be a lot of confusion over this subject.  The issue is that 'thumb' is an overloaded concept.

1. It is an operating mode of some ARM CPUs.
2. It is an ISA.
3. It is a programmer model.

ARM has tried to create 'architecture' versions.  That is the same CPUs from the same architecture version should run the same binary.  [A list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family#Cores) can be found on wikipedia.  An architecture is usually listed as ARMv*N*, where *N* is a number.  ARMv1 to ARMv4 (approximately 1985-1998) are only ARM 32 bit ISA.  In the CPSR or system mode register there is no thumb bit.  With ARMv4, some CPUs did support thumb.  This is listed at ARMv4t.  An update in ARMv5 allowed something called 'inter-working' where a 32-bit ARM routine could call a 16-bit thumb routine.  The call would switched the mode register.  With ARMv6, some CPUs supported *Thumb-2*, which is a mixed 16/32bit ISA; but it only uses the same 'thumb' bit of the CPSR.  With ARMv7, this mixed 16/32bit mode came standard with the thumb mode bit.

Some issues with nomenclature are that mixed 16/32 bit Thumb-2 code can have different op-codes added as the architectures change.  Also, they can have extra instruction based on CPU configuration and modes.

### Thumb original

This mode had limited use of high registers (r8-r15).  It used a different register for stack.  It did not allow conditional execution of instructions.  All ALU instructions set condition codes; whereas ARM32 has an 's' bit to select whether condition codes are set. It was primarily meant to reduce code density.  The instruction set had only 16bit opcodes.  Some popular machines with this CPU set include Game Boy Advance.

### Thumb-2

While Thumb-2 includes 32bit instructions, the binary of Thumb2 is **NOT** compatible with the original ARM 32 bit ISA.  They are completely different. Also, the 'Thumb-2' has evolved over time.  It is backwards compatible, but there are different versions of 'Thumb-2'.

### UAL and Conditional execution

Along with 'Thumb-2', ARM corp added 'Unified assembler language'.  With Thumb2, almost every ISA in ARM 32bit has an opcode mapping.  The main oddity is the conditional execution.  ARM 32bit tagged each opcode with a condition code field which consumed a lot of opcode space.  This means that to achieve the same functionality (original C code) the assembler/object code is bigger.  With Thumb-2, and 'it' instruction was introduced that primes the condition registers.  The IT instruction can cause the next four instruction to execute conditionally.  This is the biggest change to produce UAL (an assembler syntax which can produce traditional ARM 32bit or Thumb32 opcodes/binary).

See also: [ARM `it` conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991476/arm-it-conditional-instruction-assembler-armcc)

### System level

Thumb-2 also added instruction to access the co-processor and to handle exceptions in Thumb-2 mode.  Earlier versions of Thumb/Thumb-2 did not allow some system level concepts, so ARM32 was required on this CPUs.  These additions to the Thumb-2 ISA allowed the Cortex-M variant.  [cortex-m](/questions/tagged/cortex-m)

## Modern day

The Thumb-2 opcode in Cortex CPUs (ARMv7+) are more compact encoding than the traditional ARM 32 bit opcodes.  They will execute faster (except some extremely pathologically cases) and have less code density.  All ARM CPUs from 2004 onward are supporting this Thumb-2 variant.  There is really no need to produce a traditional ARM 32 bit binary.  Only CPUs designed before approximately 2005 would need this functionality.

CPUs using the original 'Thumb' are extremely limited as only eight registers are available for all opcodes.  No cellphones or commercial products supporting dynamic execution for application programmers will use the 'Thumb' ISA.  Only deeply embedded devices (probably for legacy product or upgrades) will use this ISA.  The Thumb-2 shares encodings and could run Thumb binaries, but this is mainly a historical note.  The conditional execution and mixed 16/32bit ISA allows Thumb2 to supplant the ARM32 opcodes.

The hallmark of ARM/Thumb is the mode bit.  You must identify the CPU to know if Thumb/Thumb-2 is applicable.  Cortex-M CPUs will only support Thumb2 opcodes.  They do not support the traditional ARM32 opcodes.  The Cortex-A CPUs support both modes in order to run legacy ARM32 binaries (or those produced by mis-informed developers).

---

From [ARM in 2023](https://developer.arm.com/Architectures/T32%20Instruction%20Set%20Architecture),

> The T32 instruction set, known as **Thumb** in pre-Armv8 architectures, is a mixed 32- and 16-bit length instruction set that offers the designer excellent code density for minimal system memory size and cost.

As ARM tries to redefine the nomenclature, programmers should be aware of the historical naming as other 3rd party tool, OS configuration, SOC documentation, etc. may have alternate meanings to the words 'Thumb' and 'Thumb-2'.  Even this text is a misnomer as the mixed 32/16 bit ISA was known and introduced as 'Thumb-2'.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0344/c/programmer-s-model/thumb-2-instruction-set
It explains in detail about the enhancement of the Thumb2 architecture. The same covers the ARM, Thumb and Thumb2 instruction set description implicitly.