# How to calculate the offset/target address of branch instruction (`b`)

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I am working on Cortex M3 family, so I refers to the ARMv7 Thumb/Thumb-2 instruction.

I have disassembled an elf image and got an following snippet:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

1f002f58 <Reset_IRQHandler>:
1f002f58:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (1f002f60 <Reset_IRQHandler+0x8>)
1f002f5a:   469d        mov sp, r3
1f002f5c:   f000 b950   b.w 1f003200 <Reset_IRQHandler_C>
1f002f60:   20020000    andcs   r0, r2, r0

1f002f64 <Setup_RC32M>:
1f002f64:   b57f        push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, lr}

...
...

1f003200 <Reset_IRQHandler_C>:
1f003200:   4829        ldr r0, [pc, #164]  ; (1f0032a8 <Reset_IRQHandler_C+0xa8>)
1f003202:   4a2a        ldr r2, [pc, #168]  ; (1f0032ac <Reset_IRQHandler_C+0xac>)
1f003204:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
```

In `Reset_IRQHandler` there is an `b.w` instruction which encoded as `f000 b950`, and the target address of `b.w` in the disassembled text is `0x1f003200 <Reset_IRQHandler_C>`. I want to calculate the target address per to the encoded instruction `f000 b950` by myself, but I can not get the result --- `0x1f003200` at any case...

I have referred to the *ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual* and know that the encoded `f000 b950` is the T4 encoding of `b` instruction. Then I extract the `imm10`, `imm11` and other essential parameters like `S`, `I1`, `I2` specified in the manual to form a bitstring, and finally I do an signed extended on this bitstring to get a 32-bit immediate offset.

In this case, after my calculation, the immediate offset I got is 0x150, I know, since it's an Thumb2 (32-bit) instruction, it should be multiplied by 4 --- so got 0x540;

But, obviously, the current `pc` value: 0x1f002f60 (0x1f002f5c + 0x4 for prefetch), plus 0x540 is 0x1f0034a0 --- not 0x1f003200

I have struggle on this for almost whole day...
any help will be appreciated...

Comment: When I decoded `f000 b950` using T4 I got an immediate value of sign extended (0:0:0:0000000000:00101010000:0)=0x2A0 which seems right since 0x1f003200-0x1f002f60=0x2A0

Comment: Where did you get "should be multiplied by 4" from? _All_ Thumb instructions are only halfword-aligned, even [the ones composed of two halfwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28860250/3156750).

Comment: times 4 is from arm encodings (A1) all the thumb encodings have to be able to hit halfwords or even numbered addresses so the one lsbit is not needed (times 2).

Comment: @dwelch Thanks.. I ignored that truth..

Comment: @Notlikethat yeah.. I forgot that truth..