# ARM/Thumb interworking confusion regarding Thumb-2

Tags: arm, elf, disassembly, thumb

I've been going through ARM ISA related documentation since a while and so far I believe that I've got a good understanding for the basics of ARM/Thumb interworking. I'll quickly summarize that in the following:

- Instructions can be either 4 byte aligned (ARM) or 2 byte aligned (Thumb).
- Thumb and ARM instructions reside in separate regions i.e. they are not intermixed without **explicit** processor state change.
- State change can happen upon executing either of `bx`, `blx`, `ldm`, `ldr`. Choosing between ARM or Thumb depends on the value of the least significant bit in the address which can be 0 or 1 respectively.
- The current state of the processor can be either ARM or thumb. That depends on the state of bit 5 of `CPSR`.

Rules for state change can be summarized in the following figure taken from this [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2555748):

[image: thumb state change rules]]

However, Thumb-2 instructions have confused me a bit. For instance, let's inspect the encoding of instruction `ADC` which can be found in section `A8.8.2` of the ARMv7-A/R reference manual. Basically, the same instruction has 3 distinct encodings 16 bit (Thumb), 32 bit (Thumb2), and 32 bit (ARM).

Here are my questions:

- Does the 32-bit Thumb-2 instructions execute in ARM or Thumb mode of the processor? (I'm assuming its the latter but not sure)
- Some resources mention that ARM/Thumb instructions can be "freely" intermixed in thumb-2. Does that mean **explicit** state change using `bx`, `blx`, `ldm` or `ldr` doesn't need to happen?

Final note, this is the closest [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669905/arm-thumb-and-thumb-2-instructions-confusion) to mine, however, I'm focusing on interworking.

Comment: 32-bit Thumb instructions are still Thumb instructions, so nothing changes in that respect; as explained in the link Thumb-2 is just the name of the feature set that introduced the capability for 32-bit encodings in the first place. Can you give an example of "Some resources..."? They may be referring to the unified assembly language rather than the actual machine code, and/or the fact that Thumb-2 also introduced Thumb versions of most of the instructions which were previously only availible in ARM.

Comment: @Notlikethat For instance, this question on disassembly  (http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/how-to-detect-thumb-mode-in-arm-disassembly) is mixing ARM and Thumb in the same object file without explicit call to _bx_ or _blx_ to change state. In that case I guess, the assembler(or linker) should automatically generate state changing instructions between ARM and Thumb?

Comment: You can _assemble_ pretty much anything you like (it's just bytes after all); whether it would actually _execute_ correctly is an entirely different matter. (That said, with the revised behaviour of PC writes in ARMv7, there is more scope for wonderfully silly in-line interworking - I reckon `sub pc, pc, #3` is the most evil). I'm pretty sure the "freely intermixed" notion is in the context of e.g. you can now use `rrx` (previously only an "ARM instruction") in your Thumb code without having to branch to a separate function written in a different syntax, by virtue of the new Thumb-2 technology

Answer (score 3):

### Choicing a mode

> so far I believe that I've got a good understanding for the basics of ARM/Thumb interworking.

Well, that is useful, it is really part of an older story.  Originally, there was only ARM 32-bit instructions (1980-mid 1990s).  Then ARM made a mode that was like a compression front-end that expanded a strictly 16bit opcodes to 32 bits.  This was **thumb** mode (mid 1990s to ~2005).  Then ARM came out with **thumb2** (which is somewhat nebulous) mainly typified by a mix of both 16bit and 32bit instructions (~2005 to current).

The concept of *interworking* is only useful for a CPU with **thumb** (old) and ARM functions.  If you have a **thumb2** CPU and a good compiler with normal memory (`1+` wait states), then the **thumb2** is almost always the best choice.

### Thumb2 intermixing

In a **thumb2** capable processor, you do not need interworking!  Ie, you don't change modes.  You can use the *thumb* 16bit encodings and if you ask for a mnemonic where this is not possible, the assembler emits a 32bit version.  The [Cortex-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M) CPUs only have a **thumb2** *mode* (really *thumb* mode with instruction extensions).

### Disassembling

There are not really three types of opcodes but two with one *extension*.

- Original 32 bit ARM opcodes.
- 16 bit only **thumb** encodings.
- the **thumb2** *extension* with all **thumb** opcodes plus more.

As the *thumb* opcodes are more dense, it is not possible to do all types of operations.  So the **thumb** `ADC` is limited compared to the ARM.  However, for most instructions ARM Holding updated the **thumb2** (the only mode in the CPU is thumb; **thumb2** is extra instructions/opcodes) to have all the capabilities of the ARM mode `ADC`.

There are discussions on recognizing the mode in a binary elsewhere.  Assuming the code is not trying to obfuscate and people made rational choices, you will only have a two types of disassembly.

1. ARM 32 bit
2. **thumb2**

A **thumb2** disassembler should work with pure **thumb** code.  Most people do not use *interworking*.  If they do, a large part of the binary will be thumb mode, with a small performance critical section in ARM mode.

A difficulty with **thumb2** is the mixed 16/32 bit can lead a disassembler to mis-interpret an instruction stream if it decodes a 32bit encoding mid stream.

> Final note, this is [the closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669905/arm-thumb-and-thumb-2-instructions-confusion) to mine, however, I'm focusing on interworking.

*Interworking* makes no sense on a **thumb2** CPU.  Since you question is tagged **disassembling**, I tried to answer with that focus versus the other questions that is mainly about what the modes are.  For *elf* disassembly, the disassembler should have no trouble to locate major function entry points and should be able to disassemble without much issues.

Comment: I think ARM holding thinks of **thumb2** as a different beast as the CPU implementation is probably **much** more tricky with both 16/32bit opcodes (at least the instruction stream decoder).  However, for any programmer  **thumb2** is sort of a *fiction*.  Thinking of **thumb2** as  an enhanced **thumb** mode that can do everything the ARM mode can is probably most useful.  Since it can do everything, *interworking* is useless.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that nowadays "interworking is useless". Hence, there is no need to support it in the disassembly tool I'm working on. Supporting **thumb2**  should be then sufficient to experiment with the whole range of ARMv7.

Comment: dont forget there is more than one definition of thumb2 extensions, armv6m has only a small number of thumb2 extensions, armv7m added something like 100 to 150 instructions.  and I have not looked at armv8 nor have I looked at any nuances with a non-cortex-m armv7 thumb2 support.(cortex a/r).  they are most definitely extensions to thumb (which itself has potentially armv4, armv5, armv6, armv7, armv8 differences)

Answer (score 2):

> Does the 32-bit Thumb-2 instructions execute in ARM or Thumb mode of the processor?
>
> **Thumb-2 instructions are accessible** as were Thumb instructions **when the processor is in Thumb state**, that is, the T bit in the CPSR is 1 and the J bit in the CPSR is 0. <sup><sub>([source](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344c/Beiiegaf.html))</sub></sup>

---

> Some resources mention that ARM/Thumb instructions can be "freely" intermixed in thumb-2. Does that mean explicit state change using bx, blx, ldm or ldr doesn't need to happen?

No state change needs to happen, since Thumb-2 instructions and ordinary Thumb instructions execute in the same state. As for how this fits with the instruction encoding, the *ARM Architecture Reference Manual : Thumb-2 Supplement* says this:

> The new 32-bit Thumb instructions are added in the space previously occupied by the Thumb BL and BLX
> instructions. This is made possible by treating the BL and BLX instructions as 32-bit instructions, instead of
> treating them as two 16-bit instructions.