# Assembling THUMB instrutions to execute on Cortex-M3

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, cortex-m, thumb

As an exercise, I want to let STM32F103 execute from internal SRAM. The idea is to write some THUMB assembly by hand, assemble it with `arm-none-eabi-as`, load the machine code into SRAM with OpenOCD's `mwh` instruction, set PC to the beginning of SRAM with `reg pc 0x20000000`, and finally `step` a few times.

Here is the assembly code I want to execute. It's basically a pointless loop.

```
# main.S
.thumb
.syntax unified

mov r0, #40
mov r1, #2
add r2, r0, r1
mvn r0, #0x20000000
bx r0
```

I need to get the machine code so that I can load it into SRAM, but the disassembler output doesn't seem to be right.

```
$ arm-none-eabi-as -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -o main.o main.S
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -d -m armv7 main.o

main.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f04f 0028   mov.w   r0, #40 ; 0x28
   4:   f04f 0102   mov.w   r1, #2
   8:   eb00 0201   add.w   r2, r0, r1
   c:   f06f 5000   mvn.w   r0, #536870912  ; 0x20000000
  10:   4700        bx  r0
```

Shouldn't the THUMB instructions be 16-bits in length? The machine code I got take 4 bytes per instruction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the ARM, Thumb and Thumb 2 instruction encodings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669905/what-is-the-difference-between-the-arm-thumb-and-thumb-2-instruction-encodings)

Comment: @P__J__ Thanks for the helpful link, but it doesn't answer my question. The accepted answer says "most instructions have 2-byte encodings, but `bl` and `blx` have always had 4-byte encodings", but in my question `mov`, `add`, and `mvn` are encoded as 32-bit words, despite the `.thumb` directive. I want an answer explaining how to target the Thumb instruction set, or "Thumb instruction encoding" to be specific.

Comment: your code looks ARM for me.

Comment: That's thumb code.  The instructions are 32 bit long because they are all thumb2 instructions.  Only a select subset of instructions can be encodd in 16 bit and yours are not among those.

Comment: Use `movs` and `adds`; the 16-bit thumb form of most instructions is the flag-setting version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The STM32F103 is cortex-m3 based.  You need to start with the st document where it says that then go to arms website get the cortex-m3 technical reference manual.  In that it tells you this is based on the armv7-m architecture and so you get the architectural reference manual.  And then you can BEGIN to start programming.

Running from flash the normal way uses a vector table, running from ram can mean that depending on the boot pins, but if you want to download the program using the debugger you are on the right path you just got stuck or stopped before finishing.

```
# main.S
.thumb
.syntax unified

mov r0, #40
mov r1, #2
add r2, r0, r1
mvn r0, #0x20000000
bx r0
```

You specified unified syntax and perhaps on the command line cortex-m3?  or armv7-m?  So you ended up with thumb2 extensions they are two 16 bit halves as documented by ARM (armv7-m architectural reference manual shows you all the instructions).  They are variable length the first one is decoded the second one is just operands.  The non-thumb2 are all 16 bit, the bl/blx were/are two separate 16 bit instructions, but the cortex-ms want those to be back to back where on prior cores you could actually separate them to demonstrate they were truly two different instructions.

so for example

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

add r2, r0, r1
adds r2, r0, r1

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   eb00 0201   add.w   r2, r0, r1
   4:   1842        adds    r2, r0, r1
```

The 16 bit "all thumb variant" encoding is with flags only so you have to put adds; if gnu assembler and you specified unified syntax, which most folks are going to tell you to do, I do not personally. Just so you know:

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

add r2, r0, r1
adds r2, r0, r1

so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:6: Error: instruction not supported in Thumb16 mode -- `adds r2,r0,r1'
```

so

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

add r2, r0, r1
add r2, r0, r1

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   1842        adds    r2, r0, r1
   2:   1842        adds    r2, r0, r1
```

Just to warn you in case you fall into that trap.  And do not you just love that the disassembler uses adds.

Anyway.  So these are fine, these are

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

mov r0, #40
mov r1, #2
add r2, r0, r1
mvn r0, #0x20000000
bx r0


00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f04f 0028   mov.w   r0, #40 ; 0x28
   4:   f04f 0102   mov.w   r1, #2
   8:   eb00 0201   add.w   r2, r0, r1
   c:   f06f 5000   mvn.w   r0, #536870912  ; 0x20000000
  10:   4700        bx  r0
```

Like add the 16 bit encoding of mov is with flags so

```
movs r0, #40
movs r1, #2

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   2028        movs    r0, #40 ; 0x28
   2:   2102        movs    r1, #2
   4:   eb00 0201   add.w   r2, r0, r1
   8:   f06f 5000   mvn.w   r0, #536870912  ; 0x20000000
   c:   4700        bx  r0
```

and we know about add now

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   2028        movs    r0, #40 ; 0x28
   2:   2102        movs    r1, #2
   4:   1842        adds    r2, r0, r1
   6:   f06f 5000   mvn.w   r0, #536870912  ; 0x20000000
   a:   4700        bx  r0
```

The mvn makes no sense you want to branch to 0x20000000 two things, first you want 0x20000000 not 0xDFFFFFFF so try this

```
   0:   2028        movs    r0, #40 ; 0x28
   2:   2102        movs    r1, #2
   4:   1842        adds    r2, r0, r1
   6:   f04f 5000   mov.w   r0, #536870912  ; 0x20000000
   a:   4700        bx  r0
```

Second this is a cortex-m so you can't bx to an even address that is how you switch to arm mode but this processor does not do that so you will fault.  You need the lsbit set.  So try this

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

movs r0, #40
movs r1, #2
adds r2, r0, r1
ldr r0, =0x20000001
bx r0

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   2028        movs    r0, #40 ; 0x28
   2:   2102        movs    r1, #2
   4:   1842        adds    r2, r0, r1
   6:   4801        ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; (c <.text+0xc>)
   8:   4700        bx  r0
   a:   0000        .short  0x0000
   c:   20000001    .word   0x20000001
```

With gnu assembler the ldr equals thing will pick the most efficient (smallest instruction) solution if it can otherwise it pulls from the pool.

Or you could do this and not use the pool

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

movs r0, #40
movs r1, #2
adds r2, r0, r1
mov r0, #0x20000000
orr r0,r0,#1
bx r0
```

This makes my skin crawl because you want to orr not add, but this would make it a halfword shorter if that matters:

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

movs r0, #40
movs r1, #2
adds r2, r0, r1
mov r0, #0x20000000
adds r0,#1
bx r0

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   2028        movs    r0, #40 ; 0x28
   2:   2102        movs    r1, #2
   4:   1842        adds    r2, r0, r1
   6:   f04f 5000   mov.w   r0, #536870912  ; 0x20000000
   a:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   c:   4700        bx  r0
```

Then you need to link.  But...

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

movs r0,#0
loop:
   adds r0,#1
   b loop
```

Link without a linker script to make this quick

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x20000000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000020000000
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.elf
    
so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

20000000 <_stack+0x1ff80000>:
20000000:   2000        movs    r0, #0

20000002 <loop>:
20000002:   3001        adds    r0, #1
20000004:   e7fd        b.n 20000002 <loop>
```

Open two windows, in one start openocd to connect to the board/chip

In the other

```
telnet localhost 4444
```

When you get the openocd prompt assuming that all worked

```
halt
load_image so.elf
resume 0x20000000
```

Or you can resume 0x20000001 since that feels better but the tool is fine either way.  Now

```
halt
reg r0
resume
halt
reg r0
resume
```

Being an stm32 and being all thumb variant instructions this example will work on any stm32 I have heard of so far.

What you will see is that r0 it will increment, the human time between resuming and halting again it will count many times times you can see the number change to see that the program is running.

```
telnet localhost 4444
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Open On-Chip Debugger
> halt
> load_image so.elf
6 bytes written at address 0x20000000
downloaded 6 bytes in 0.001405s (4.170 KiB/s)
> resume 0x20000000
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x20000002 msp: 0x20001000
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x000ED40C
> resume 
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x20000002 msp: 0x20001000
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x001C8777
>
```

If you want to then put it in flash, assuming the blue pill (this is a blue pill right?) does not have a write protected flash which some do, but you can easily remove that (will let you figure that out, is not necessarily easy, pro tip a complete power cycle is involved at some point).

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

.word 0x20001000
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:
movs r0,#0
loop:
   adds r0,#1
   b loop

arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x08000000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008000000
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.elf
    

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_stack+0x7f80000>:
 8000000:   20001000    .word   0x20001000
 8000004:   08000009    .word   0x08000009

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   2000        movs    r0, #0

0800000a <loop>:
 800000a:   3001        adds    r0, #1
 800000c:   e7fd        b.n 800000a <loop>
```

The reset vector needs to be address of handler ORRED with one. And the vector table needs to be at 0x08000000 (or 0x00000000 but you will end up wanting 0x08000000 or 0x02000000 for some not this one, 0x08000000 for this one, read the docs).

In the telnet into openocd

```
flash write_image erase so.elf
reset
halt
reg r0
resume
halt
reg r0
resume
```

And now it is programmed in flash so if you power off then on that is what it runs.

openocd will end with something like this

```
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
```

then the telnet session

```
telnet localhost 4444

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Open On-Chip Debugger
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xa1000000 pc: 0x0800000a msp: 0x20001000
> flash write_image erase so.elf
auto erase enabled
device id = 0x20036410
flash size = 64kbytes
wrote 1024 bytes from file so.elf in 0.115819s (8.634 KiB/s)
> reset
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800000a msp: 0x20001000
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x002721D4
> resume
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800000a msp: 0x20001000
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x0041DF80
>
```

If you want the flash to reset into ram you can do that

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

.word 0x20001000
.word 0x20000001
```

Power cycles it should ideally crash/fault but if you use openocd to put something in ram like we did before

```
flash.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_stack+0x7f80000>:
 8000000:   20001000    .word   0x20001000
 8000004:   20000001    .word   0x20000001



so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

20000000 <_stack+0x1ff80000>:
20000000:   2000        movs    r0, #0

20000002 <loop>:
20000002:   3001        adds    r0, #1
20000004:   e7fd        b.n 20000002 <loop>

telnet localhost 4444
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Open On-Chip Debugger
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800000a msp: 0x20001000
> flash write_image erase flash.elf
auto erase enabled
device id = 0x20036410
flash size = 64kbytes
wrote 1024 bytes from file flash.elf in 0.114950s (8.699 KiB/s)
> load_image so.elf
6 bytes written at address 0x20000000
downloaded 6 bytes in 0.001399s (4.188 KiB/s)
> reset
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x20000002 msp: 0x20001000
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x001700E0
> resume
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x20000004 msp: 0x20001000
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x00245FF1
> resume
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x20000002 msp: 0x20001000
> reg r0
r0 (/32): 0x00311776
>
```

but a power cycle

```
telnet localhost 4444
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Open On-Chip Debugger
> halt
> reset
stm32f1x.cpu -- clearing lockup after double fault
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Handler HardFault
xPSR: 0x01000003 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0x20000fe0
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
> halt
>
```

Yeah, not happy as expected/desired.

Note _start comes from an ENTRY(_start) in a default linker script, it is not special nor really hard-coded into the tools (nor is main for gcc, that comes from a default bootstrap).

So you can do this

so.s

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
movs r0,#0
loop:
   adds r0,#1
   b loop
```

so.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    hello : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > hello
}


arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T so.ld so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

20000000 <loop-0x2>:
20000000:   2000        movs    r0, #0

20000002 <loop>:
20000002:   3001        adds    r0, #1
20000004:   e7fd        b.n 20000002 <loop>
```

and the _start warning goes away.  Note that the section names you create in the linker script (hello in this case) do not have to be ram, rom, flash, etc they can be what you want and yes you could do this with a linker script but without a MEMORY section in the file and only SECTION.

If you choose to

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
```

openocd can read elf files and some others but a raw memory image like that you have to specify the address otherwise you might get 0x00000000 or who knows what

```
load_image so.bin 0x20000000
```

If/when you get some nucleo boards, you can simply copy the bin file to the virtual thumb drive and it will load it into the target mcu for you and the virtual drive will sort of reload or will reload and show a FAIL.TXT if it did not work one way that happens is if you link for 0x00000000 instead of 0x08000000.  You can't load for sram that way though, just flash.  But I assume you have a blue pill not a nucleo board.

That is the long answer.

### Short answer

Those are thumb2 extensions they are two halfwords in size.  See the armv7-m architectural reference manual for the instruction descriptions.  They are perfectly fine for this chip.

You probably want to use load_image not mwh on openocd, but mwh will work if you get your halfwords in the right order.

You ideally want to link although as written your code or mine is position independent so arguably you could just extract the instructions and use mwh.

The chip has a boot from sram mode which would/should use a vector table not just launch into instructions, you would need to get the boot pins set right and use something like openocd to load the program into ram, then reset (not power cycle).

MVN move negative or negate is not the right instruction here and you need the lsbit set before using bx so you want 0x20000001 in the register, something like

```
ldr r0,=0x20000001
bx r0
```

for gnu assembler, or

```
mov r0,#0x20000000
orr r0,#1
bx r0
```

but that is for armv7-m, for cortex-m0, m0+ some of the -m8s you can't use those instructions they will not work.

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
.syntax unified
mov r0,#0x20000000
orr r0,#1
bx r0

arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:5: Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `mov r0,#0x20000000'
so.s:6: Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `orr r0,#1'
```

So use the ldr = pseudo instruction or load from the pool manually, or load 0x2 or 0x20 or something like that then shift it and load another register with 1 and orr it or use add (yuck).

### Edit

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
.globl _start
_start:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
b .


00000000 <_start>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <_start+0x4>)
   2:   e7fe        b.n 2 <_start+0x2>
   4:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

If it cannot generate a single instruction then it will generate a pc relative load and put the variable in a literal pool, somewhere after a branch if it can find one.

But you can do this yourself too

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
.globl _start
_start:
ldr r0,myvalue
b .
.align
myvalue: .word 0x12345678


00000000 <_start>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <myvalue>)
   2:   e7fe        b.n 2 <_start+0x2>

00000004 <myvalue>:
   4:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

> The literal pool is an area of memory (in the text segment), which is used to store constants.

```
unsigned int fun0 ( void )
{
    return 0x12345678;
}
unsigned int fun1 ( void )
{
    return 0x11223344;
}
00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e59f0000    ldr r0, [pc]    ; 8 <fun0+0x8>
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
   8:   12345678    .word   0x12345678

0000000c <fun1>:
   c:   e59f0000    ldr r0, [pc]    ; 14 <fun1+0x8>
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   11223344    .word   0x11223344
```

Not unusual to have the C compiler do this and put it at the end of the function.

```
    .global fun1
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun1, %function
fun1:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    ldr r0, .L6
    bx  lr
.L7:
    .align  2
.L6:
    .word   287454020
    .size   fun1, .-fun1
```

I did not build that for thumb/cortex-m but that is fine it would do the same thing.  But, saying that:

```
unsigned int fun0 ( void )
{
    return 0x12345678;
}
unsigned int fun1 ( void )
{
    return 0x00110011;
}

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <fun0+0x4>)
   2:   4770        bx  lr
   4:   12345678    .word   0x12345678

00000008 <fun1>:
   8:   f04f 1011   mov.w   r0, #1114129    ; 0x110011
   c:   4770        bx  lr
```

Since I have a rough idea of what immediates you can use for the various arm instruction sets.  Likewise

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
.globl _start
_start:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00110011
nop
nop
nop
b .

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <_start+0x10>)
   2:   f04f 1111   mov.w   r1, #1114129    ; 0x110011
   6:   bf00        nop
   8:   bf00        nop
   a:   bf00        nop
   c:   e7fe        b.n c <_start+0xc>
   e:   0000        .short  0x0000
  10:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
```

By using the ldr = thing gnu assembler will pick the optimal instruction.  This is not supported by all arm assemblers (assembly language is defined by the tool not the target), and not all will choose the optimal instruction some may always generate the pc-relative ldr if they recognize the syntax at all.

It is somewhat meant to be used to get the address of a label for example

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
.globl _start
_start:
ldr r0,=mydataword
ldr r1,[r0]
add r1,#1
str r1,[r0]
bx lr

.data
mydataword: .word 0
```

being in another segment it can't resolve this at assembly time so it leaves a placeholder for the linker

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (c <_start+0xc>)
   2:   6801        ldr r1, [r0, #0]
   4:   f101 0101   add.w   r1, r1, #1
   8:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]
   a:   4770        bx  lr
   c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 -Tdata=0x2000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (100c <_start+0xc>)
    1002:   6801        ldr r1, [r0, #0]
    1004:   f101 0101   add.w   r1, r1, #1
    1008:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]
    100a:   4770        bx  lr
    100c:   00002000    andeq   r2, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00002000 <__data_start>:
    2000:   00000000
```

Or

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
.globl _start
_start:
ldr r0,=somefun
ldr r1,[r0]
orr r1,#1
bx r1
.align
somefun:
    nop
    b .
```

even in the same segment

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <somefun+0x4>)
   2:   6801        ldr r1, [r0, #0]
   4:   f041 0101   orr.w   r1, r1, #1
   8:   4708        bx  r1
   a:   bf00        nop

0000000c <somefun>:
   c:   bf00        nop
   e:   e7fe        b.n e <somefun+0x2>
  10:   0000000c    .word   0x0000000c


00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (1010 <somefun+0x4>)
    1002:   6801        ldr r1, [r0, #0]
    1004:   f041 0101   orr.w   r1, r1, #1
    1008:   4708        bx  r1
    100a:   bf00        nop

0000100c <somefun>:
    100c:   bf00        nop
    100e:   e7fe        b.n 100e <somefun+0x2>
    1010:   0000100c    andeq   r1, r0, r12
```

If you let the tools do the work though

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified
.globl _start
_start:
ldr r0,=somefun
ldr r1,[r0]
bx r1
.align
.thumb_func
somefun:
    nop
    b .
```

You do not need to orr in the lsbit, the tool does it for you

```
00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (100c <somefun+0x4>)
    1002:   6801        ldr r1, [r0, #0]
    1004:   4708        bx  r1
    1006:   bf00        nop

00001008 <somefun>:
    1008:   bf00        nop
    100a:   e7fe        b.n 100a <somefun+0x2>
    100c:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9
```

These are all or mostly cases of the literal pool being used to help out with an instruction set like this that is somewhat fixed in length so has a limit on immediate values.

Sometimes you can help gnu assembler as to where to put the pool data

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

.globl fun0
.thumb_func
fun0:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
bx lr
.globl fun1
.thumb_func
fun1:
ldr r0,=0x11223344
bx lr
.align
.word 0x111111

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (c <fun1+0x8>)
   2:   4770        bx  lr

00000004 <fun1>:
   4:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (10 <fun1+0xc>)
   6:   4770        bx  lr
   8:   00111111    .word   0x00111111
   c:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
  10:   11223344    .word   0x11223344
```

but if I

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

.globl fun0
.thumb_func
fun0:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
bx lr
.pool
.globl fun1
.thumb_func
fun1:
ldr r0,=0x11223344
bx lr
.align
.word 0x111111

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <fun0+0x4>)
   2:   4770        bx  lr
   4:   12345678    .word   0x12345678

00000008 <fun1>:
   8:   4801        ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; (10 <fun1+0x8>)
   a:   4770        bx  lr
   c:   00111111    .word   0x00111111
  10:   11223344    .word   0x11223344
```

So

```
ldr r0,=something
```

Means at link time or sometime load the address of something into r0.
Labels are just addresses which are just values/numbers so

```
ldr r0,=0x12345678
```

Means the same thing the label is instead the value itself so give me the address of that label which is 0x12345678 and put that in r0, so it is an interesting extension of that notion that gas or someone thought of, probably arms assembler, I do not remember then others adopted it as well or improved upon it or whatever.  Note if you want to do it yourself you do this

```
ldr r0,something_address
b .
.align
something_address: .word something
```

because something is a label which is an address which is a value you do not put the equals there, the equals is just for the ldr instruction.  Same as the vector table:

```
.word 0x20001000
.word reset
```

And lastly you can do one of these to get the function address correct for so called thumb interwork

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word handler
.word broken

.thumb_func
reset:
    b .

.type handler,%function
handler:
    b .
    
broken:
    b .

Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_stack+0x7f80000>:
 8000000:   20001000    .word   0x20001000
 8000004:   08000011    .word   0x08000011
 8000008:   08000013    .word   0x08000013
 800000c:   08000014    .word   0x08000014

08000010 <reset>:
 8000010:   e7fe        b.n 8000010 <reset>

08000012 <handler>:
 8000012:   e7fe        b.n 8000012 <handler>

08000014 <broken>:
 8000014:   e7fe        b.n 8000014 <broken>
```

Can use .thumb_func if in thumb you can use .type label,%function both in arm mode and thumb mode and you can see that it generates the proper thumb address in the vector table, but where neither were used the broken label is not generated correctly so that vector would fault on a cortex-m.

Some folks sadly do this:

```
.word reset + 1
.word handler + 1
.word broken + 1
```

to try to fix that rather than using the tool as intended.  Other assembly languages for arm/thumb meaning other tools (ARM, Kiel, etc) have their own syntax and rules this is limited to gnu assembler.

Also note how much of this answer was just command line stuff, I examined the output of the tool and manipulated it until I got what I wanted, did not have to load and run code to see what was going on.  Just use the tools.

### Edit 2

Reading the rest of your question in the comment

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

ldr r0,=0x12345678
nop
b .


00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4801        ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <.text+0x8>)
   2:   bf00        nop
   4:   e7fe        b.n 4 <.text+0x4>
   6:   0000        .short  0x0000
   8:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
```

Putting the .word at offset 6 would be an alignment fault for an ldr so they need to pad it to put it at a word aligned address.

By now you should have downloaded the armv7-m architectural reference manual from ARM's website or elsewhere.  And you can see at least in the one I am looking at (these are constantly evolving documents)  the T1 encoding

```
imm32 = ZeroExtend(imm8:'00', 32); add = TRUE;
```

and further down

```
Encoding T1 multiples of four in the range 0 to 1020
```

and

```
address = if add then (base + imm32) else (base - imm32);
data = MemU[address,4];
R[t] = data;
```

The offset (immediate) encoded in the instruction is the number of words relative to the pc.  The pc is "two ahead" or address of the instruction plus 4 so for the ldr r0 instruction

```
   0:   4801        ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <.text+0x8>)
   2:   bf00        nop
   4:   e7fe        b.n 4 <.text+0x4>  <--- pc is here
   6:   0000        .short  0x0000
   8:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
```

8 - 4 = 4; 4>>2 = 1 so 1 word away from the pc, instruction 0x48xx the xx is 0x4801 to indicate one word.  Here again the alignment to use this instruction.

So what if we

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

nop
ldr r0,=0x12345678
b .


00000000 <.text>:
   0:   bf00        nop
   2:   4801        ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <.text+0x8>)
   4:   e7fe        b.n 4 <.text+0x4>
   6:   0000        .short  0x0000
   8:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
```

that seems broken

```
Operation

if ConditionPassed() then
  EncodingSpecificOperations();
  base = Align(PC,4);
  address = if add then (base + imm32) else (base - imm32);
  data = MemU[address,4];
  if t == 15 then
    if address<1:0> == '00' then LoadWritePC(data); else UNPREDICTABLE;
  else
    R[t] = data;
```

When you see all of the pseudo code, then a pc of 6 in this case

Then continuing to read the documentation to understand the pseudo code

> Calculate the PC or Align(PC,4) value of the instruction. The PC value of an instruction is its address plus 4 for a Thumb instruction. The Align(PC,4) value of an instruction is its PC value ANDed with 0xFFFFFFFC to force it to be word-aligned.

so 0x6 & 0xFFFFFFFC = 4.  8 - 4 = 4;  4>>2 = 1; so 0x4801.

If we force the thumb2 instruction

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

ldr.w r0,=0x12345678
b .
```

It still aligns probably to save us from faults the thumb2 version can reach odd values

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f8df 0004   ldr.w   r0, [pc, #4]    ; 8 <.text+0x8>
   4:   e7fe        b.n 4 <.text+0x4>
   6:   0000        .short  0x0000
   8:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
```

Note the 4 at the end of the instruction that is pc + 4, but what if we tried to do this:

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
.syntax unified

ldr.w r0,something
b .
something: .word 0x12345678
```

Comment: Great answer!!! Can you elobrate on the "pulls (address) from the pool" part, though? The pseudo insturction `ldr r0, =0x20000001` is converted to `ldr r0, [pc, #4]` with the address constant stored in an word at `0xC`. Why doesn't gas put it at `0xA` instead of `0xC` to save a half word, and why is it `[pc, #4]` if `0xC - 0x6 = 6`?

Comment: I believe it’s because the cpu can’t load 32 bits from a non-%4 address—it’ll get an alignment fault.

Comment: LOL I hit the character limit for an answer again.  That last thing did generate an instruction that is an unaligned access.  The tools are saving you from that, but you can make it happen, and as such you should sprinkle .aligns all over the place and/or examine the disassembly.   The 16 bit ldr (literal) can only do aligned accesses and it will try to use the 16 bit if you dont specify which instruction you want, if it can.

Comment: Also note that in gnu assembler .align is supported across most if not all of the targets, but what it aligns to with or without a number varies, so you have to be careful, so far for arm targets with no number it aligns on a word boundary.  .balign is more portable and often preferred in gnu assembler.  YMMV.  When starting a block of data (.text or .data) not a bad idea to put .align in there and it will do what you want, you will see that compiled code it will use it in front of every function, possibly burning a few bytes.