# Questions about IT conditional codes in assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, thumb

Most examples have IT commands such as the following,

```
ITTE   NE        ; IT can be omitted
ANDNE  r0,r0,r1  ; 16-bit AND, not ANDS
ADDSNE r2,r2,#1  ; 32-bit ADDS (16-bit ADDS does not set flags in IT block)
MOVEQ  r2,r3     ; 16-bit MOV

ITT    AL        ; emit 2 non-flag setting 16-bit instructions
ADDAL  r0,r0,r1  ; 16-bit ADD, not ADDS
SUBAL  r2,r2,#1  ; 16-bit SUB, not SUB
ADD    r0,r0,r1  ; expands into 32-bit ADD, and is not in IT block

ITT    EQ        
MOVEQ  r0,r1
BEQ    dloop     ; branch at end of IT block is permitted

ITT    EQ
MOVEQ  r0,r1
BKPT   #1        ; BKPT always executes
ADDEQ  r0,r0,#1
```

I want to look at for example the last IT block in the examples.
Im really confused what is happening. For MOVEQ, I thought it was checking if r0 = r1, and moving r1 into r0 if they were equal. But that doesn't make sense if they are equal. What is really going on?

I wrote a thumb code that checks which number is greater:

```
cmp r0, r1
ITE HS
movhs r0, r0
movlo r0, r1
```

Here I needed to compare registers before the IT block...
But why do all the examples not include a comparison atleast before hand? Would there been another way to write an IT block for my example that doesn't include a comparison? What's really going on in these examples?

Comment: Unfortunately, most explanation are written for a program familiar with ARM assembler, trying to use THUMB2 and `IT`.  In this case, you have set the condition code before and this is similar to the 'conditional branch' instructions present in almost all assembler/machine architectures.  So the documentation/examples usually assumes you know this and only show what needs to be added to ARM code (the `IT` statement) with the condition after which explain the `IT` encoding (`ITE` vs `ITT`, etc).

Comment: Related: [ARM IT conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991476/arm-it-conditional-instruction-assembler-armcc).  As explained for Thumb2, the IT is an actual instruction which sets data in the status register.  The instructions within a block are just normal opcodes.  So, the suffix 'NE/EQ' within a block are not significant for Thumb2 (they are for ARM32).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flags are an input to predicated instructions inside an IT block.  Yes, you do put a `cmp` or `adds` or whatever other flag-setting instruction at some point before an `it`.  It doesn't have to be *right* before.

The examples you show exist to document corner cases for `IT`, not full/complete examples of using it to actually do something specific.

The documentation for a conditional branch instruction doesn't typically show flag-setting instructions either.

---

According to [ARM's docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjabicci.html)

> With the exception of CMP, CMN, and TST, the 16-bit instructions that normally affect the condition code flags, do not affect them when used inside an IT block.

But one of the examples does clearly show that you can change flags with a 32-bit `adds` inside an IT block, and this tells us that regular compare/test instructions are allowed.

The docs don't make it clear that changes to flags *within* an IT block have an effect on later predicated instructions inside the block.  @DanLewis's answer confirms that they do.

In ARM mode, no IT block is needed to predicate execution (4 bits in every instruction encode a predicate) so flag-setting instructions obviously affect later instructions.  It makes sense that it works the same way in Thumb mode, especially since `IT` is optional in some syntaxes.  (Some assemblers will insert it for you in unified syntax if assembling for thumb mode.)

Comment: That makes much more sense. I originally thought (being called an IF Then and all) that it was doing comparisons inside the block. So for an IT block, you set the flags before hand, and then the IT block conditions those flags and performs the op codes accordingly. Can flags change inside the IT block? Thank you!

Comment: @Darklink9110: yes, you can change flags inside an IT block, the docs are clear on that.  They're not clear on whether that has any effect on the *rest* of the current block.

Answer (score 1):

> @Darklink9110: yes, you can change flags inside an IT block, the docs are clear on that. > They're not clear on whether that has any effect on the rest of the current block.

I tested the following two functions on an ARM Cortex-M4 (Thumb-2) to find out, and it turns out that if an instruction inside an IT block changes the flags, then subsequent instructions in the same IT block (1) such as ADC, SBC, and RRX do use the new flag values, and (2) may have their enabled/disabled status changed according to the new flag values.

```
//      Inside an IT block, do instructions that use the carry flag (e.g., ADC) see
//      changes to the carry flag caused by previous instructions in the same IT block?

Test1:  MOV         R0,1        // R0 = 1
        CMP         R0,R0       // C  = 0, Z = 1 (EQ)
        ITT         EQ
        LSRSEQ      R0,R0,1     // C  = 1, Z = 1 (EQ), R0 = 0
        ADCEQ       R0,R0,0     // R0 = R0 + C
        BX          LR          // **Returns 1 in R0**

//      Do flags that are changed by instruction in an IT block update which
//      subsequent instructions in the same IT block are enabled/disabled?

Test2:  MOV         R0,1        // R0 = 1
        CMP         R0,R0       // Z  = 1 (EQ)
        ITT         EQ
        CMPEQ       R0,0        // Z  = 0 (NE)
        MOVEQ       R0,0        // R0 = 0 ? (Disabled!)
        BX          LR          // **Returns 1 in R0**
```